# How can i select top numbers from array column in postgresql 9.4

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, sorting, postgresql-9.4

```
create table foo_table(foo_id int, foo_array int[], some_other_column text)

insert into foo_table(foo_array) values (ARRAY[1,3,8,32,55])
insert into foo_table(foo_array) values (ARRAY[2,4,9,31,38,92,99])
insert into foo_table(foo_array) values (ARRAY[5,12,15,35,47])
insert into foo_table(foo_array) values (ARRAY[6,7,13])
```

The foo_array arrays will have variable number of elements.
All the array elements will be unique and all the numbers in all arrays will also be unique.

I wonder that how can i select biggest 5 numbers from foo_array column which in that case would be 99,92,55, 47, 38.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.nr
from foo_table
  cross join lateral unnest(foo_array) as t(nr)
order by nr desc
limit 5
```

Alternatively somewhat shorter:

```
select unnest(foo_array) nr
from foo_table
order by nr desc
limit 5
```

Using a set-returning function in the select list is somewhat deprecated - or a least discouraged.

Comment: As I can't think of any other way - yes this is the fastest way (because it's the only way). But don't expect this to be blazingly fast - but that's the price you pay for not normalizing your data.